# Applications of total least squares and related pitfalls (in biology/ecology)

Tags: regression, correlation, ecology, total-least-squares

I recently discovered TLS for a bio-statistical (ecological) problem I am working on. However, I was not able to find a lot of (ecological) literature that uses TLS in their analysis. From other disciplines I mainly found papers that focus on image recognition, that look at calibrating instruments for measurement error, and some biomedical studies.

Now, my question is, why is that? Has this method just not penetrated to fields like ecology, am I not looking in the right places, or is there a technical or theoretical reason for not applying it? Apart from the usual assumptions that have to be met (normality, homoscedasticity, etc.), are there pitfalls that are not obvious to the non-statistician (and literature on that issue)?

What are other fields where TLS has been applied more frequently?

Lastly, I will give the example I am working on to illustrate what kind of application I have in mind: I have two variables taken from a spider web, let’s say web size and strength of silks, which are correlated. A slope coefficient, however, cannot be obtained from a correlation so I turned to regression - only that there is no logical reason for either web size or silk strength to be chosen as a predictor (and, additionally, measurement error exists in both variables). Does it not make sense to thus use TLS, as the slope in OLS depends on which variable is chosen as the predictor? Why is TLS (apparently) not used in such a way? Is there an alternative I don't know about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not common but it does get used in ecology. I've found that the terminology for this family of methods is quite inconsistent between fields, though, and this may be why you have not found it in your literature searches. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares):

> This [...] is
> variously known as **standardised major axis** (Ricker 1975, Warton et
> al., 2006), the **reduced major axis**, the **geometric mean
> functional relationship** (Draper and Smith, 1998), **least products
> regression**, **diagonal regression**, **line of organic correlation**, and the
> **least areas line** (Tofallis, 2002).

(emphasis mine)

Other identical or closely related terms: **Deming regression**, **orthogonal regression**, and **major axis regression**. In ecology, **standardised major axis regression** is the most common term. Though it also goes by the term **Model II regression**, at least in the [R package `lmodel2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmodel2/vignettes/mod2user.pdf) developed for this by an ecologist, Pierre Legendre. I've found that this term is completely unfamiliar to statisticians from other disciplines.

Here's just a few papers and packages in ecology that use these methods, based on some quick googling. Note that many of these have to do with allometric scaling relationships, where it is of obvious use:

Schulte-Hostedde, A. I., Zinner, B., Millar, J. S., & Hickling, G. J. (2005). Restitution of mass–size residuals: validating body condition indices. *Ecology*, 86(1), 155-163.
https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/04-0232

Warton, D. I., Duursma, R. A., Falster, D. S., & Taskinen, S. (2012). smatr 3–an R package for estimation and inference about allometric lines. *Methods in Ecology and Evolution*, 3(2), 257-259.
https://sciences.ucf.edu/biology/d4lab/wp-content/uploads/sites/23/2017/01/Warton-etal-2012.pdf

White, C. R., Cassey, P., & Blackburn, T. M. (2007). Allometric exponents do not support a universal metabolic allometry. *Ecology*, 88(2), 315-323.
https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/05-1883

Shipley, B. (1995). Structured interspecific determinants of specific leaf area in 34 species of herbaceous angiosperms. *Functional Ecology*, 312-319.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2390579?origin=crossref

These methods have their downsides, though, and despite their advantages it is sometimes better to use simple OLS. For example, I don't think it's possible to use random effects with these models, and sometimes that is of greater importance than OLS vs. TLS. For another point against them, I quote Edwards et al. (2015) summarising an argument from Smith (2009):

> [Standardised major axis regression] fits a line through the middle of the data that does not
> change if the roles of “predictor” and “response” variables are
> switched; in contrast, ordinary least squares regression yields a
> different fitted line if the y-axis and x-axis are switched (Warton et
> al. 2006). However, SMA regression has a different limitation, because
> substantial natural variation in the response variable [...] will
> increase the apparent steepness of the allometric slope (Smith 2009).
> This occurs because the SMA estimator for the slope of y vs. x is the
> standard deviation of y divided by the standard deviation of x (Smith
> 2009).

It's worth reading Smith (2009) to understand this better. I should add that because the terminology is so variable, it's possible that there are subtle methodological differences that mean that not all critiques in this paper apply to TLS.

Edwards, K. F., Thomas, M. K., Klausmeier, C. A., & Litchman, E. (2015). Light and growth in marine phytoplankton: allometric, taxonomic, and environmental variation. *Limnology and Oceanography*, 60(2), 540-552.
https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/lno.10033

Smith, R. J. (2009). Use and misuse of the reduced major axis for line‐fitting. *American Journal of Physical Anthropology: The Official Publication of the American Association of Physical Anthropologists*, 140(3), 476-486.
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ajpa.21090

Comment: Wow, thats a lot of points to explore further, thanks a lot!